# Passing dependencies to classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I have a couple of classes stored in an array. However they need some dependencies from a third-part.

They have a common method called abc() and that abc-method is the one needing the different dependencies.

So my idea is either giving each class some injection-method and then call them in the abc() method or perhaps there is a way to do this when the classes are initialized?

I know which classes are supposed to be initalized and I also know what dependencies they need.

From the beginning the paths to each class is stored in a configuration array.

```
array('Abc\Bcd\Class','Abc\Bcd\Class2')
```

etc.

Then each class is loaded like this

```
foreach (array as item)
{
   $another_array[] = new item()
}
```

Perhaps I could inject my dependencies there?

Any ideas?

Comment: You know there are systems specially designed for dependency injections? Like http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: Sure but I'm looking for a open solution I don't want any third-part dependencies to make this work

Comment: It's just 1 small class: https://raw.github.com/fabpot/Pimple/master/lib/Pimple.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use __autoload to determine what PHP files are required for a certain class.

> See: [PHP: Autoloading Classes - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)